# UI automation tool for a windows based WPF application with Record and Playback feauture

Tags: wpf, ui-automation

I am in the process of recommending an UI automation tool for a windows based WPF application in a company
Which targets wide range of customers . The Application lives on a layer of WCF services for getting
The data. The company is already having a small VBScript framework  written specifically for Test Complete
and is really not robust, Hence I am lookout for a right tool, where we could reuse the scripts or
Improve the already existing tool. Any ideas are welcome.

I have looked at Microsoft UI Automation, Project White, UIA Verify and Ranorex. Each one of them
Is having  a feature lack.

I was able to go through the process of Microsoft UI Automation. I am still in the process of understanding how it works
  with WPF, since it is totally dependent on Automation IDS.
 Our application is huge and is not written with this in mind. All the code either does not implement
Automation ID property or Name property which is very much essential for object identification in the visual tree
in tools like UISpy  and VisualUIAVerify.

What I am looking in specific are the following. Please give ratings to each of these

1) Recording : Recording , play back     and automatic execution of test scripts and generate a report.

2) Dependencies : Minimal Dependencies(.NET frameworks, API modules , SDK Versions etc..)

3) )Code Generation : Code Generation of test scripts from Templates, Macros  and Recording.

4)Object Name Mapping:  Avoid explicit usage of Automation IDS and screen corrdinates,  if they use, does it support any tools which would take XAML   Files and insert  Automation IDS into  it and also avoid Problems With duplicate Automation IDS.

5) Events: Any Events and call backs that the user(tester) may receive if the GUI has undergone any changes
    and how the scripts would change in this Case.

6) Support : Support for different scripting languages and easy Code conversions(C#, VBScript, Python.. etc)

7) Fast and  Reliable: Easy  and fast accessibility of  GUI elements  for manipulation( Like support to xml dom, Json.. etc), navigation, code duplication        replacement tasks for changes in UI and easy configuration(xml, ini files)

8)Code Converters: the tester writes code in vbscript and  developer could simply convert it into c# for embedding  them into any stand alone framework if need be).

9)Custom controls:  Support for custom controls and object mapping. If you have a custom object that behaves like one of standard controls.  are you able to map (tell the test tool that the custom control behaves like the standard) control? Does it support all the standard controls methods? Can you add the custom control to it’s own class of control?

10)Reports: Should be able to execute multiple tests at once and generate a report similar to VisualUIAVerify.

Comment: I am very interested in what you find out also.

Answer (score 3):

**[Visual Studio 2010 Coded UI Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726%28VS.100%29.aspx)**

> You can use Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate or Visual Studio 2010 Premium to create automated tests of the user interface known as coded UI tests. These tests provide functional testing of the user interface and validation of user interface controls.

---

I am using Coded UI Tests to automate tests of a WPF application built on the [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) pattern. The [record/playback](http://blogs.msdn.com/mathew_aniyan/archive/2009/11/05/tutorial-coded-ui-test-beta2.aspx) features of the tool are impressive, generating really nice models. For large suites, the advice is to [tear apart the generated code](http://blogs.msdn.com/balagans/archive/2009/11/12/9921231.aspx), structuring and extending it for your own purposes.

I recommend [Visual UIA Verify](https://github.com/T800G/UIAutomationVerify) to assist viewing the automation structure of your application while developing and debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried AutomatedQA testcomplete
http://www.automatedqa.com/products/testcomplete/